# Pythonic way of getting hierarchy of elements in numeric list

Tags: python

I have a numeric list a and I want to output a list with the hierarchical position of every element in a (0 for the highest value, 1 for the second-highest, etc).

I want to know if this is the most Pythonic and efficient way to do this.  Perhaps there is a better way?

```
a = [3,5,6,25,-3,100]
b = sorted(a)
b = b[::-1]
[b.index(i) for i in a]
```

Comment: You can save one line by `b = sorted(a,reverse=True)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ThierryLathuille's answer works only if there are no duplicates in the input list since the answer relies on a dict with the list values as keys. If there can be duplicates in the list, you should sort the items in the input list with their indices generated by `enumerate`, and map those indices to their sorted positions instead:

```
from operator import itemgetter
mapping = dict(zip(map(itemgetter(0), sorted(enumerate(a), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)), range(len(a))))
```

`mapping` becomes:

```
{5: 0, 3: 1, 2: 2, 1: 3, 0: 4, 4: 5}
```

so that you can then iterate an index over the length of the list to obtain the sorted positions in order:

```
[mapping[i] for i in range(len(a))]
```

which returns:

```
[4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also you `numpy.argsort(-a)` (`-a` because argsort assumes ascending order). It *could* have better performance for large arrays (though there's no official analysis that I know of).

Comment: blue_note, based on how I asked the question, I marked blhsing's answer as correct, but for what I'm actually trying to do, your answer is by far the most elegant.  It would actually look like this: np.argsort(a)[::-1]

Comment: -a might be faster than inverting

Answer (score 1):

One problem with your solution is the repeated use of `index`, that will make your final comprehension O(n**2), as `index` has to go over the sorted list each time.

It would be more efficient to build a `dict` with the rank of each value in the sorted list:

```
a = [3,5,6,25,-3,100]

ranks = {val:idx for idx, val in enumerate(sorted(a, reverse=True))}
# {100: 0, 25: 1, 6: 2, 5: 3, 3: 4, -3: 5}
out = [ranks[val] for val in a]

print(out)
# [4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 0]
```

in order to have a final step in O(n).

Answer (score 0):

First, `zip` the list with `a` with `range(len(a))` to create a list of tuples (of element and their positions), `sort` this list in reverse order, `zip` this with `range(len(a))` to mark the positions of each element after the sort, now unsort this list (by sorting this based on the original position of each element), and finally grab the position of each element when it was sorted

```
>>> a = [3,5,6,25,-3,100]
>>> [i for _,i in sorted(zip(sorted(zip(a, range(len(a))), reverse=True), range(len(a))), key=lambda t:t[0][1])]
[4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 0]
```